# highchart not shown data graph

Tags: highcharts

I have a really strange behavior with highchart (via rails plugin): The graph display without the graphlines but the data exists because when point to the graph it's show the little box with the data.

http://www.alderia.com/highchart1.png

When I open firebug, the lines in the graph appear...

http://www.alderia.com/highchart2.png

The thing is that the same thing happens with Chromium... so it's something not specific to firefox.

Comment: Do you have some code we can look at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highcharts line chart does not work with jQuery 1.7.

http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog

Comment: also It does not work with jQuery 1.8.2, do you know the solution to this problem ?