# highchart inside facebox does not show up values

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, facebox

I am using [highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts) inside [facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) to draw a chart. I can see the x-axis, y-axis, but not the values.. If I select the entire chart by dragging mouse, I can see the values. Which means that for some reason the chart is not being drawn. What could be the problem ?
Also I have a facebook login inside facebox, I can see the login button, but it does not work. Whereas similar login button on the main page works fine.

I tried my highchart code in jsfiddle, it works fine.

Here is how am I using facebox,

```
comp.append(hTag);

    $('#statLeftRightId').append(comp);

    jQuery.facebox({ div: '#statLeftRightId' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with HighCharts 2.2.1 and jQuery 1.7.1. I found that using jQuery 1.6.1 drew the charts.

As the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848090/highchart-not-shown-data-graph) thread indicates, there are some problems with jQuery 1.7.1. So I doubt this is a facebox problem.

Comment: yes. I faced other problems also with JQuery 1.7.1, so moved back to 1.5.1